# Backstage: RepoUrlPicker load allowedOrganizations, allowedOwners, etc. based on user identity?

Tags: templates, permissions, backstage

We have different Teams in our Organization that have access to different Collections on our on prem Azure DevOps server. Is it possible to load different allowedOrganizations, allowedOwners, ...,  based on the user identity provided by the Azure AD? I couldnt find anything related to this in the Backstage Documentation.

It is mentioned in the Documentation that it is possible to authorize a whole parameter with backstage:permissions but i couldn't figure out if its possible to enable/disable specific options for the allowedOrganizations.